# Updating date , but i got error message: "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"

Tags: laravel

I'm new in laravel 6x
if i try post , I got "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object" error.And error line in ProudctsController

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // dd($request->all());
    DB::beginTransaction();
    Try{
        $product = Product::created([
            "product" => $request->product,
            "price" => $request->price,
            "stock" => $request->stcok,
            "description" => $request->description,
        ]);
        if($request->hasFile('images') ){
            $arrayImages = [];
            foreach ($request->images as $value) {
                $path = $value->store('product/create');
                $columnSImage = [
                    "product_id" => $product->id,
                    "image" => $path,
                ];
                array_push($arrayImages,$columnSImage);
            }
            ImagesProductDB::insert($arrayImages);
        }
        DB::commit();
    } catch (\Exception $e){
        DB::rollback();
        dd($e);
    }
    return redirect()->back();
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Product::create([...`, instead of `Product::created([...`?

Comment: the `$product` is null the `created` method is wrong in this context !

Comment: `created` isn't a function of a model. Simply use `create` instead.

Comment: thank you it turns out to just change the created to create

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`created` to `create`

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // dd($request->all());
    DB::beginTransaction();
    Try{
        $product = Product::create([
            "product" => $request->product,
            "price" => $request->price,
            "stock" => $request->stcok,
            "description" => $request->description,
        ]);
        if($request->hasFile('images') ){
            $arrayImages = [];
            foreach ($request->images as $value) {
                $path = $value->store('product/create');
                $columnSImage = [
                    "product_id" => $product->id,
                    "image" => $path,
                ];
                array_push($arrayImages,$columnSImage);
            }
            ImagesProductDB::insert($arrayImages);
        }
        DB::commit();
    } catch (\Exception $e){
        DB::rollback();
        dd($e);
    }
    return redirect()->back();
```